# Проблема в реализации побитового вычитания UNIX C

Tags: c, алгоритм, unix, битовые-операции

`введите сюда код`Проблема в реализации функции побитового вычитания. Проблема всегда начинается, когда идёт последовательность вычитания из 0 единицы.

В функциию всегда приходят положительные `value_1` and `value_2` , где `value_1 > value_2`.

---

```
    void make_sub(my_decimal value_1, my_decimal value_2, my_decimal *result) {
      memset(result, 0, sizeof(my_decimal));
      int carry = 0, diff;
      for (size_t i = L_BITS; i < MAN_BITS; ++i) {
        diff = get_bit(&value_1, i) - get_bit(&value_2, i) - carry;
        carry = (diff == -1) ? 1 : 0;
        if (abs(diff) == 1) set_bit(result, i);
      }
    }
```

> В начале реализовывал вычитание через дополнительный код, но для моего
> типа данных это не подходит, так как отричательные числа от
> положительных отличается только установкой крайнего бита в положение
> 1.

*Как иначе переписать функцию, чтобы та выполняла вычитание коректно и без костылей?*

---

*Как иначе реализовать пока не придумал.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не все ситуации у вас просчитаны.

Результат вычитаний может быть от `-2` до `1`.
Результат неправильно просчитывается при `0 - 1 - 1`. `carry` должен быть с единицей, а бит нулю.

Подправим как в школе столбиком.
Добавляем 2 и ставим перенос.

```
void make_sub(my_decimal value_1, my_decimal value_2, my_decimal *result) {
      memset(result, 0, sizeof(my_decimal));
      int carry = 0, diff;
      for (size_t i = L_BITS; i < MAN_BITS; ++i) {
        if (get_bit(&value_1, i) >= get_bit(&value_2, i) + carry ) {
          diff = get_bit(&value_1, i) - get_bit(&value_2, i) - carry; 
          carry = 0;
        } else {
          diff = get_bit(&value_1, i) + 2 - get_bit(&value_2, i) - carry; 
          carry = 1;
        }
        if (diff)
          set_bit(result, i);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Мне нужно впредь перестать обращаться с отрецательными числами в подобных реализациях.

Comment: Операции `+` и `-` не определены на битах. Было бы логично не использовать их в реализации вычитания.

Comment: здесь математика вычислений с основанием 2, а не логика. и результат отрицаний иногда не влазит в один бит. математический подход пойдёт. @Stanislav Volodarskiy